# how to convert string '03-January-2023' to datetime on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table into which I want to convert a string to datetime and insert. However I am getting a conversion failed error

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_PURCHASE([PURCHASE_DATE], [PURCHASE_TIME], [PURCHASE_CITY]) 
SELECT CAST( '03-January-2023' AS DATETIME2) AS PURCHASE_DATE,  
[PURCHASE TIME] AS PURCHASED_TIME, [PURCHASE_CITY] FROM CUSTOMERS_INDIA
```

Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can I get some advice/ help on how I can resolve this? I am using Microsoft SQL

Comment: Considering that you are using a literal, why not just use an unambiguous literal, such as `yyyyMMdd`?

Comment: Also, have you have a look at the [Date and time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles)?

Comment: as in using with a convert statement? I am picking the date from another table and inserting into a different table.

Comment: So you are storing date (and time) values as a `varchar`? That's the *real* problem. Fix your design. **Never** store date (and time) values as a string; use a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Actually it gets created that way on Azure, thats why I am trying to move them to a different table. when it gets created through ADF all the columns default as nvarchar(max) for some reason. its a no knowledge table, gets built on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try_convert()` ... It will return a NULL rather than throwing an error if the conversion fails

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),SomeCol varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'03-january-2023')
,(2,'03 jan 2023')
,(3,'03 ZZZ 2023')
,(4,'Just a a string')
 

Select ID
      ,NewValue = try_convert(datetime,SomeCol)
 from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
ID  NewValue
1   2023-01-03 00:00:00.000
2   2023-01-03 00:00:00.000
3   NULL
4   NULL
```